# Table with checkboxes and ng-repeat (angular JS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-table, material-design

I want to make a table, based on this model (Material Design Lite) :

https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#tables-section

In my code, I have a list, and I try to display it, in the following way, by using a ng-repeat :

```
                    <table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-data-table--selectable mdl-shadow--2dp">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Id. administrateurs</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="admin in listAdmins">
                            <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric" ng-model="adminselected">{{admin}}</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
```

But the result is not the same than in the illustration example :[image: Admin list]

As we can see, there is no checkbox on the left and I don't understand why.

Also, how to make a table, where we can directly add data on it ?

In fact, with a fixed list, it works. But mine is generated by a request in a database, and its value can be changed. My listadmin is empty at the beginning, and it is completed by an authentification process.

Comment: you can use angular [ui-grid.info]

Answer (score 0):

Your code work correct.

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <!-- Material Design Lite -->
    <script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    <!-- Material Design icon font -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <script>
      angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.listAdmins = ['admin1', 'admin2', 'admin3'];
      }]);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MainController as main">
       <table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-data-table--selectable mdl-shadow--2dp">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Id. administrateurs</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="admin in listAdmins">
                            <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric" ng-model="adminselected">{{admin}}</td>
                        </tr>

                      </tbody>
                    </table>     
  </body>
</html>
```

May be some errors occurred? Can you see browser console.

Comment: It works, when I do the example in the model, but with ng-repeat, It does'nt work.

I have no problem in my console.

Comment: What html is obtained after the compilation of the angular? May be result html has some corrupt tags?

Comment: The screen that I have posted on this topic. Obtained after compilation of node/angular.

Comment: In fact, if I remove the ng-repeat, there is no problem. But the fact is that I need it to print my data, and manipulate it !

Comment: Screenshot i saw. I talked about html tags on page (e.g. Tab 'Elements' in dev console Chrome browser). May be tags do not compile correct.

Comment: Is variable "listAdmins" string array, or array of objects? May be angular dublicate exception occurred?

Comment: It is an array of string. I see no exception.

Comment: No problem of compilation with the tags. Moreover, they are displayed on the page.

Comment: I change my code (add angular part). He works correct. I think you have some custom css styles, that breake html.

Comment: I suppress all of my css.style, I have still the problem... Sorry :-(

Comment: In fact, with a fixed list, it works. But mine is generated by a request in a database, and its value can be changed.
My listadmin is empty at the beginning, and it is completed by an authentification process.

Comment: I was able to replicate this situation. I use $timeout service gor this.
I think It is bug in component. Looks like component build only one time by class names. You need write to developers or use another component.